# Plot complete graph using if else statement in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I need to plot theoretical curve on Matlab using the equations. I wrote the code on Matlab for all of the equations as follows;

```
%file name myeqs.m       
 function [P] = myeqs(v,tau0,Gd,Le)
    % P = myeqs(v,tau0,Gd,Le)
    % Input arguments:
         v = 1; 
         tau0 = 0.3;
         Gd = 0.01;
         Le = 1;
         specimen = 5;
```

Then to plot the curve, wrote the code as follow;

```
figure,plot(v,P)
```

I tried different set of input parameters but everytime I am getting a straight line in the output graph as shown in the image here.
[image]

I calculated the values from the equations and found out that I am only getting one part of the curve from the If-else-statement used in the above code. Can someone please help me out to correct the coding. 
How can I get the all of the values of v in column A and all of the corresponding values of P in column B of the excel sheet?

Thank you

Comment: In `myeqs` you overwrite your input arguments, so it always outputs the exact same value.

Comment: @Cris Luengo Thanks alot